# Interpretation of the characteristics for amplifier circuits with and without a filter

Tags: amplifier, filter, microwave

I've run simulations in AWR software for hmc414 amplifier without and with filter on output.
The conclusion after the first simulation is that this amplifier is unilateral.
[image]

Unfortunately I don't know how to refer to the characteristics of the amplifier with a filter on the output. How to interpret it and what does it imply? Does anyone have any idea?

[image]

Comment: Yes https://www.brighthubengineering.com/power-generation-distribution/97352-understanding-smith-charts/

Comment: But this link is for Smith Chart and i'm using polar charts

Comment: Outer scale says 15 max (dB) 5 dB/div. From f.min to f.max and polar phase shift ,s21 is forward gain , 10 sweep triangles starting at 1.5GHz